# Is it possible to use a PixelBufferPool with AVPlayerItemVideoOutput.copyPixelBuffer?

Tags: ios, performance, opengl-es, avfoundation, cvpixelbuffer

From my recent experience, using a PixelBufferPool to store pixel buffers instead of creating new ones all the time can yield quite strong performance improvement.

In my app I'm reading buffers from a video using [copyPixelBuffer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayeritemvideooutput/1386148-copypixelbuffer). From the doc it seems that there's no way to pass a pointer to the buffer to manage the memory usage. If true, why is that? Isn't it a strong performance loss? If false, how can I do so?

Comment: Great question! Did you figure anything out? Any tips on improving the performance in this domain?